# Как скрыть див один за другим через javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как скрыть див один за другим через javascript? Я сделал но чета не получается!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.div').hide();
        next();
    }, 1000);
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #567;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">Div 1</div>
<div class="div">Div 2</div>
<div class="div">Div 3</div>
<div class="div">Div 4</div>
<div class="div">Div 5</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сразу задать каждому элементу свой таймаут:

```js
function delayedHide(i,o) {
  setTimeout(
    function(){
      $(o).hide();
    },
    600 * (i + 1)
  );
}

$(function() {
  $('.hideme').each( delayedHide);
});
```

```css
.hideme {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #567;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hideme">Div 1</div>
<div class="hideme">Div 2</div>
<div class="hideme">Div 3</div>
<div class="hideme">Div 4</div>
<div class="hideme">Div 5</div>
```

Не удержался, переименовал класс..

Answer (score 4):

А вот так это можно сделать без *jQuery*:

```js
function hideOne(elements, index) {
    if (index < elements.length) {
        elements[index].style.display = "none";
        ++index;
        setTimeout(hideOne.bind(null, elements, index), 1000);
    }
}
function hide() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
    setTimeout(hideOne.bind(null, elements, 0), 1000);
}
```

```css
.div {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #567;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<body onload="hide();">
    <div class="div">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div">Div 2</div>
    <div class="div">Div 3</div>
    <div class="div">Div 4</div>
    <div class="div">Div 5</div>
</body>
```

Можно сразу установить таймауты для скрытия всех div'ов:

```
function hideOne(element) {
    element.style.display = "none";
}
function hide() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("div");
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; ++i)
        setTimeout(hideOne.bind(null, elements[i]), 1000 * (i + 1));
}
```

Comment: Способ получше предыдущего.